# GTK+ underscores - physically painful

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, typing

Programming with GTK+ is annoying and physically painful because of the sheer amount of reaching out for the "_" key. For anyone with actual GTK+ experience, have you found a work around for this?. The platform is linux based.

Comment: What editor/ide? You can probably bind a more convenient key.

Answer (score 1):

Use an editor with code completion support. Eclipse, Vim, and Emacs can all do this.

Comment: I have tried many editors, but usually resort to Vim in the end. Ill look into the auto complete and the key bindings - thanks - this place is way more friendly than the gtk+ irc

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard

Comment: A bit of an overkill, don't you think?

Comment: Anyone who experiences physical pain should be considering drastic measures.  Notice that he didn't say, it's *annoying* or I can't type it *accurately*, but used the word *pain*.

Answer (score 1):

Either use autocompletion, or reassign your underscore key to another, more reachable one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to use the api of gtk+ - then try vala, pygtk or binding in language of your preference.
If you wish to modify core then use autocomplete,macros.